# jQuery Supersized iphone orientation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I used jQuery extension Supersized on my website. At the beginning background is fine, but when I change the orientation in iPhone/iPad landscape/portrait background isn't fullscreen. You can check it in: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html.

When I used viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

background is ok, but I don't want to use it, because then I'd have to rebuild the content of the page. What can I do?